# Python - Как поменять формат выходных данных в функции

Tags: python, python-2.x

Столкнулся с ситуацией, которую не могу решить.

Есть функция, которая берет данные с сайта по IP. При ее вызове, возвращает данные в формате кортежа, а мне данные необходимы в словаре.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Код функции и ее вызов

```
    def request_auth_by_api(command='user_info', params={}):
        nonce = int(round(time.time()*1000))
        sync_param = {"nonce": nonce}
        params.update(sync_param)
        params = urllib.urlencode(params)

        H = hmac.new(api_secret, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
        H.update(params)
        sign = H.hexdigest()

        headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   "Key": api_key,
                   "Sign": sign}
        try:
            conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.exmo.com")
            conn.request("POST", "/v1/{}".format(command), params, headers)
            response = conn.getresponse()
            json_obj = json.load(response)
            status = response.status
            reason = response.reason
            conn.close()
        except:
            json_obj = {}
            status = False
            reason = False
        return json_obj, status, reason


    response = request_auth_by_api()
    print (type(response))
    print response
```

[image: вывод функции в формате кортежа]

Comment: кортежи это пары?

Comment: Почему вы не опубликовали функцию в вопросе?

Comment: Реализацию функции покажите

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka это неизменяемые списки

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример, в каком виде данные возвращает функция, и как вам нужно.

Comment: Необходимо получить значение BTC

Answer (score 1):

`return json_obj, status, reason`  замените на `return json_obj[u'BTC'], status, reason`

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Помогла строчка return json_obj['balances']['BTC'], status, reason

Comment: Но есть еще один вопрос. Если бы  необходимо было взять один параметр с этой функции, то все было бы отлично. Но это главная функция, которая берет данные с сайта в виде словаря и хотелось бы от нее получить данные тоже в виде словаря, чтобы  в других функциях эти данные обрабатывать.  А у меня получается при присвоении к переменной response, данные становятся кортежем.

Comment: @ALeks вы возвращаете три переменные — словарь (спаренный JSON) и 2 строки (status и reason). Таким образом получается, что функция возвращает кортеж состоящий из трёх элементов — словаря и 2 строк. Думаю удобней возвращать только json_obj, а в случае exception возвращать status и reason.